# Best practice to change current view from a class

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift3

I'm working with Swift 3 and I'd like to change my view from a function in my class when login succeed.

I've got a *LoginViewController* which contains this function:

```
static let sharedInstance = LoginViewController()

//...

func showNextView() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        guard let eventVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(
            withIdentifier: "EventsTVC") as? EventsTableViewController else {
                assert(false, "Misnamed view controller")
                return
    }
    self.present(eventVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

In my class `APIManager`, I call this function inside my asynchronous method using ***Alamofire***:

```
func processAuth(_ data: [String: String]) {
    print("-- auth process started")

    //... defining vars

    Alamofire.request(tokenPath, method: .post, parameters: tokenParams, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: tokenHeader)
        .responseJSON { response in
            guard response.result.error == nil else {
                print(response.result.error!)
                return
            }

            guard let value = response.result.value else {
                print("No string received in response when swapping data for token")
                return
            }

            guard let result = value as? [String: Any] else {
                print("No data received or data not JSON")
                return
            }

            // -- HERE IS MY CALL
            LoginViewController.sharedInstance.showNextView()

            print("-- auth process ended")
    }
}
```

My console returns this error message:

> -- auth process started 
> 2017-03-18 20:38:14.078043  Warning: Attempt to present  on
>    whose view is not in the window
>   hierarchy!
>   -- auth process ended

---

I think it's not the best practice to change my view when my asynchronous method has ended.

I don't know what I've got to do. Currently, this is the process:

1. User opens the app and the `LoginViewController` is displayed, if no token is saved (Facebook Login)
2. In the case where it has to login, a button "Login with Facebook" is displayed
3. When login succeed, I send Facebook data in my `processAuth()` function in my `APIManager class`
4. When my API returns me the token, I saved it and **change the view to EventsTVC**

---

I put in bold where the problem is. And I would like to know if it's the best practice in my case. If so, how to avoid my error message?

I hope I made myself understood. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What actually happens is that your singleton instance `LoginViewController` wants to present itself while not being in the view hierarchy. Let me explain it thoroughly:

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    static let sharedInstance = LoginViewController()

    func showNextView() {
        ...
        // presentation call
        self.present(eventVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
```

In this function you are calling `present()` from your singleton instance on itself. You have to call it from a view which is (preferably) on top of the view hierarchy stack. The solution would probably be not using a singleton on a VC in the first place. You should be instantiating and presenting it from the VC that is currently on the screen. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @dvdblk! I will try it. And what do you think about the method I used?